# How do I fill in placeholders with a PowerShell array?

Tags: powershell

I am working on filling in placeholders on another ps1 file with an array of data. I get the content from my template and try to fill in the appropriate placeholders ({0}, {1}, {2}, etc.) and I keep getting an error saying "Input string was not in a correct format." The data in the array is in the correct index to match the placeholders, so $FormatArray[0] fills in placeholder {0}.

```
    $FormatArray = @(
        [String]$Name
        [String]$Version
        [String]$Vendor
        [String]$CloseApps
        [String]$PreInstall
        [String]$Install
        [String]$PostInstall
        [String]$PreUninstall
        [String]$Uninstall
        [String]$PostUninstall
    )


    #creating new package with PSADT files  
    Copy-Item -Force -Recurse $TemplateDirectory -Destination $Destination
    
    #populating new package placeholders
    $Template = Get-Content -Path ($Destination + "\Deploy-Application.ps1") -Raw #Preferably a relative path so it's not hard-coded
    $Formatted = $Template -f $FormatArray
    Out-File -FilePath $Destination -InputObject $Formatted -Force
```

I am new to PowerShell and cant find anything on Google about filling in placeholders with an array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `Deploy-Application.ps1` contain any literal `{`'s or `}`'s, other than the placeholders? If so you need to escape them

Comment: {} Literal's are only for variables right? If so then no. Would braces defining blocks of code interfere?

Comment: I got it working, turns out the curly brackets defining code blocks did matter, I doubled them, so { turned into {{

Comment: @NateyBee If you think that the way you solved your problem could be of interest to future readers, I encourage you to post the solution _as an answer_ (which you can [self-accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) after 48 hours)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with the advice from Mathias R. Jessen. I did have other curly braces interrupting my placeholders. I doubled all other curly braces for example.

```
If(boolean) {{ statement }}
```